# Relationships retrieve user emails

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to understand how I can join the tables `users` and `teams` to `members` in fact ?

### Users Table:

```
id |   name  |         email          |     password
 1     alain        alain@gmail.com          *****
 2     eric         eric1@gmail.com          *****
```

### Teams Table:

```
id |     name          
 1      R.O.S    
 2      Stephanois
```

### Members Table:

```
id |     user_id  (email)        |    team_id (name)
 1          1                             1
 2          2                             1
```

### DataBase:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('members', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
            $table->integer('team_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->foreign('team_id')->references('id')->on('teams');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

 public function up()
        {
            Schema::create('teams', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->increments('id');
                $table->string('name');
                $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
                $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
                $table->timestamps();
            });
        }
```

### User Model:

```
protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

public function team(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\Team', 'user_id', 'id'); ?
    }

public function member(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\Member', 'user_id', 'id'); ?
    }
```

### Team Model:

```
protected $fillable = [
        'user_id', 'name'
    ];

public function member(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Member', 'team_id'); ?
    }

public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'id', 'user_id'); ?
    }
```

### Member Model:

```
protected $fillable = [
        'id', 'user_id', 'team_id'
    ];

public function team(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Team', 'team_id');
    }

public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'id', 'user_id'); ?
    }
```

I thank you in advance for your help

Edit: when I log in with the user 'alain@gmail.com' I don't retrieve the information for the user 'alain@gmail.com' ? ie user_id and team_id.

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {   

        $user = $request->user();
        $members = Member::query()
        ->when($user->hasRole('admin') !== true, function (Builder $query) use ($user) {
         $query->where('id???', $user->email); ????
        })
        ->when($request->has('search'), function (Builder $query) use ($request) {
        $query->where('name??', 'like', '%' . $request->input('search') . '%');
         })->with('team:id,name') 
        ->paginate(5);

        return view('admin.members.index', compact('members'))
        ->with('display_search', $user->hasRole('admin'));

    }
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve here?? a user can only belongs to a team or to many teams??

Comment: @ zahid hasan emon: the user can only belongs to a team... :-) But, do hink you the others relationships are correct? please ?

Comment: Not so sure what are you trying to achieve..if you are using members table to figure out which user belongs to which team, then I am sure you will be needing many to many relationship..If not, you need to explain what are you actually trying to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which one is you're trying to achieve is not enough clear. If I guess, you want to find out which `user` is in which `team` then, in this situation you can go through -

**User.php** model -

```
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'password',
];
public function member(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Member', 'user_id', 'id');
}
```

**Member.php** model -

```
protected $fillable = [
        'id', 'user_id', 'team_id'
    ];

public function team(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Team', 'team_id');
}

public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id', 'id');
}
```

**Team.php** model (keep as it is for now)-

```
class Team extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name'
    ];
}
```

And finally call your members those are already in a team in your controller method-

```
$members = Member::with('team', 'user')->get();
return view('your-blade-file-name', compact('members'));
```

And, in your blade file -

```
@foreach($members as $member)
     <p>Name: {{ $member->user->name }} , Email: {{ $member->user->email }} , Team - {{ $member->team->name }}</p>
@endforeach
```

**Output:**

```
Name: alain, Email: alain@gmail.com , Team - R.O.S

Name: eric, Email: eric1@gmail.com , Team - R.O.S
```

Comment: hen I log in with the user 'alain@gmail.com' I don't get the information from the user `alain@gmail.com`, is it my function index() is doesn't correct ? I have edited my first message.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a user can belong to a single team, then you don't need an intermediate table. Just add a column in the user table like `team_id` that will hold the value of which team the user belong.

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('email')->unique();
    $table->string('password');
    $table->unsignedInteger('team_id'); //make it nullable or anything based on your need
    $table->rememberToken();
    $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::create('teams', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

And now make the relationships in the models:

`User` Model

```
protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password','team_id'
    ];

public function team()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Team', 'team_id');
    }
```

`Team` Model

```
protected $fillable = [
        'name'
    ];

public function users()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\User', 'team_id');
    }
```

In the above relationships a user belongs to a single team and a team has many users. I am pretty sure you are trying to achieve this. Feel free to ask if you find anything hard to understand.

> Look you don't need the intermediate model `Member`. If you want a many to many relationship then you need to use an intermediate table.